# For GUI, is there any way to get actual position of a slider thumb? (Whatever GUI.HorizontalSlider, GUILayout.HorizontalSlider, EditorWindow.IntSlider

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I'm trying to code an Editor-only window similar to Animation or Timeline.
At present, stucking in the slider thumb, which usually looks like a vertical line across the tracks.
Two ideas to implement it:
1.Customize the GUIStyle of thumb. But it seems that the thumb image cannot display out of slider rect.
2.Get position of thumb on window, and draw a vertical line individually. But for the first step, I haven't found any way given by Unity.

Of course, without any other solution, maybe I can forget about the GUI Slider and make it by myself, but sounds not an efficient plan, I hate doing this:P

Need some tips, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please confirm you need to add a dedicated Editor-only window which will not show up in the game or the build. I ask this because new-comers to Unity confuse IMGUI with actual game UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you're set to do a custom Editor window or panel, drop IMGUI coding completely and switch to UIToolkit as the Editor supports it now. Start [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateCustomInspector.html). UI Toolkit is the newest UI Framework in Unity and is also available for runtime builds.

While legacy IMGUI still works I would guess that Unity Technologies will remove it from the libraries once the Editor will be fully migrated to UI Toolkit. And while it's not 100% done, it's quite stable and the features are quite spread out.